# issue with spring boot while upgrading to 1.3.0.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Hi i just upgraded to spring boot 1.3.0.RELEASE and while running the same again get this strange error

```
14:43:52.503 [main] INFO  c.test.whf.service.HfServices - Starting up....
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.addCollectionConverters(Lorg/springframework/core/convert/converter/ConverterRegistry;)V from class org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedConversionService
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedConversionService.<init>(RelaxedConversionService.java:52)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.modifyProperties(RelaxedDataBinder.java:148)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.doBind(RelaxedDataBinder.java:128)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.bind(DataBinder.java:715)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.doBindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:267)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.bindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:240)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.bindToSpringApplication(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:220)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:171)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:161)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:146)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:163)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101)
    at com.wellmanage.whf.service.HfServices.main(HfServices.java:97)
```

also there have been no other changes to my code not sure what is causing this really .

app class is as simple as below

```
  SpringApplication.run(HfServices.class, args);
```

Please help ...

Comment: I have the same error while using Spring Boot 1.3.0 and Spring 4.2.2. Upgrading to Spring 4.2.3 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That method was added in Spring Framework and you are overriding the version explicitly in your project. *Please* don't do that!

Spring Boot is managing this for you and you should *really* let it determine the Spring Framework version to use.

Comment: thanks Stephane for this I had put 4.2.2 due to a fix (which worked in the milestone 1.3.0 versions ) that went in that release so is it that now we should let spring boot dictate the version on the underlying spring framework ?

Comment: it always was the case. If you need a _newer_ version (as you did) that's fine but once you upgrade Spring Boot you have to remember to remove that override and let Spring Boot chose it again. That method was added in 4.2.3

Comment: ahh ok thanks seems some changes have gone in for logback as well now my run fails for some logback issues let me check and resolve ..

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error too. We are currently running our applications in WebLogic, and planning to migrate to the cloud, so also enabling them to run with Spring Boot.
To fix it I needed to add this to the webapp/WEB-INF/weblogic.xml :

```
<wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>            
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
</wls:container-descriptor>
```