# IllegalAccessError in startup calling DefaultConversionService.addCollectionConverters()

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Just started getting an IllegalAccessError in my Spring Boot startup.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method org.springframework.core.convert.support.DefaultConversionService.addCollectionConverters(Lorg/springframework/core/convert/converter/ConverterRegistry;)V from class org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedConversionService
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedConversionService.<init>(RelaxedConversionService.java:52)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.modifyProperties(RelaxedDataBinder.java:148)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedDataBinder.doBind(RelaxedDataBinder.java:128)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.bind(DataBinder.java:715)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.doBindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:269)
    at org.springframework.boot.bind.PropertiesConfigurationFactory.bindPropertiesToTarget(PropertiesConfigurationFactory.java:241)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.bindToSpringApplication(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:230)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:181)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:152)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:163)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:136)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:111)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:65)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:54)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:325)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:305)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1124)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1113)
    at biz.ianw.LanCheckerReloader.Application.main(Application.java:23)
```

This appears similar to [issue with spring boot while upgrading to 1.3.0.RELEASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33799743/issue-with-spring-boot-while-upgrading-to-1-3-0-release) but I have not overridden my Spring version:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Spring 4.2.4-RELEASE appears to have selected, which contains the DefaultConversionService.addCollectionConverters() method.

I've backed out my code changes from the last couple of hours but am still getting this.

Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: Do you get this error within your IDE? What if you try and (clean) and run the app from the commandline?

Comment: You almost certainly have some old Spring jars in the classpath. Running with `-verbose:class` will let you see what is being loaded and from where

Comment: Looks like some incorrectly set up source file sharing must have been dragging some old Spring jars into the new project.  Not sure quite how it happened but I refactored the common code into a new project without any libraries and included that and it's all working now.

I'm tempted to delete this question as unhelpful unless anyone disagrees?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [issue with spring boot while upgrading to 1.3.0.RELEASE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33799743/issue-with-spring-boot-while-upgrading-to-1-3-0-release)

Answer (score 9):

I had the same problem using Spring Boot 1.3.3.RELEASE and Spring Framework 4.2.2.RELEASE. I have tried to upgrade Spring Framework version one by one and using Spring Framework 4.2.5.RELEASE the problem is solved.

Hope this helps.

Comment: spring boot 1.5.2 with 4.2.5 also fails. upgrade to 4.3.7 solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I had modular project in which one of the module was using 4.1.9 spring version. In another module My Spring boot version was 1.3.3 and spring version 4.2.5.

I did not realize the problem until I have used "-verbose:class"

The above command passed in vm arguments and then I have got information that the class is loaded from 4.1.9.

This helped me to debug what was the issue. I have changed other project dependencies to 4.2.5.

I think this problem will be resolved when we use parent pom, if we have modules in one project.